# gfortran: default include search path?

Tags: gfortran, include-path

How do you find the default search path for include files for `gfortran`?

For `gcc`, a past Q&A showed this website:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path

But,

1. I'm not sure if it applies to `gfortran`.
2. I don't think it always applies.

For example, on an Linux server, (for lack of any other method) I did this

```sh
strace gfortran try.f90 > tmp.txt 2>&1
```

and found this particular `gfortran` searches directories like

```
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.2.181/linux/ipp/lib/intel64/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/finclude
```

and it does *not* search `/usr/include` .  Apparently, this particular `gfortran` came with the Intel Fortran compiler and was customized.

So, my question is, is `strace` the only way to know what the default search paths are?  (I need to know this, because I'm remotely helping a friend.  I don't have direct access to his machine.)

**Update:**  I should have mentioned the `-print-search-dirs` option. It doesn't include the "include" search path:

```sh
gfortran -print-search-dirs | grep --color include
```

The output of `-print-search-dirs` doesn't include the directories which `strace` indicates in the above experiment of mine.

**Update2:** I've just found that the `gfortran` on ubuntu searches *only* `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/finclude`. I'm surprised that it doesn't even search `/usr/include`.  So far, it seems we have to use `-I/usr/include` whereas we don't need `-L/usr/lib` . . . Does somebody know the reason for this asymmetry?

**Update3:** The answer below shows how to list include search paths:

```sh
echo | gfortran -E -Wp,-v -
```

Unfortunately, this one lists the paths only of the preprocessor (for `#include`), not for the `INCLUDE` statement of the Fortran language.

You can verify this by looking into one of the directories which the preprocessor does search.  For example, I found `cpuid.h` in one of them. So, I compared

```
include 'cpuid.h'
```

with

```
#include "cpuid.h"
```

in a Fortran source program. Of course, either causes error, but the error messages make it clear that in the former case, the file isn't found and in the latter, the include file is found and inserted into the source code and *that* caused compile error.

Incidentally, this exercise showed that on my Linux server, `gfortran` searches /usr/lib/gcc/ . . . /**f**include among other directories whereas its preprocessor searches /usr/lib/gcc/ . . . /**include** , which kind of makes sense.

Comment: I updated my answer based on some old notes. I don't have a way of verifying that these paths are always used for the `INCLUDE` or whether it's only for the preprocessor `#include`; but it may be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

For me

```
gfortran -print-search-dirs
```

does the trick.

My version

```
gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

GNU Fortran comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Fortran
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING
```

I don't use it often and not a FORTRAN expert, so hope this helps.

**Update**

I looked back on some old notes and found this incantation:

```
echo | gfortran -E -Wp,-v -
```

Perhaps this is more useful?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, I should've mentioned that it doesn't seem to list include directories. The listing only includes "program" and "library" sections, not "include" section.

Comment: Whoops! So sorry, I should have checked more carefully.

Comment: Thank you again! Unfortunately, as you guessed, that one indeed lists the paths *only* for `cpp`.  I'll update my posting to include that information.

Comment: @Ryo Rats! I thought this would be the one. In my case (and I can't show the output) it *did* show installation-specific paths that had been compiled in (arguments to the configure script) that were search for the INCLUDE directive.